# Compiling a Qt5.2 project on OsX 10.9 with gcc4.2?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, gcc, qt5

I have a QT project that works perfectly under my current configuration ( OsX 10.8.5, QT4.8.5 and compiler i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)

The problem is I am switching to a new laptop that has OsX 10.9 installed. As known problem there is only CLang. Using CLang the project gives a lot of **compilation errors on some libraries** that I cannot change. (errors that are not given under the current configuration ).

Hence I have installed **apple-GCC4.2.1** using brew and with `gcc --version` I get:
`i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)`.

Now I get "no such file or directory" for files `<stdarg.h>` and `<float.h>`, under the directory
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1`

For what I have understood it is like it is including the basic c++ headers from the `Xcode compiler` and they do not match with the ones that gcc4.2.1 wants.

Can someone help me? thank you in advance.

Comment: Trying to install gcc on 10.9.1 with brew is something I wouldn't suggest — things can get completely screwed and keeping all paths straight is not exactly going to come easy. I would recommend just grabbing a [precompiled version](http://hpc.sourceforge.net/) and doing it that way. However, before going to all that trouble did you try setting your deployment target to something lower? Without knowing the exact errors you encountered it could be a simple fix or a tedious one.

Comment: how do I can set the deployment target? I am using -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 on the c, cxx and l flags

Comment: try doing `-mmacosx-version-min=10.6`. which version of OS X are you intending it for? It could also be that 10.7 is too low, and you need to move up to 10.8 or 10.9.

Comment: I must work on osx 10.8, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved.

**I have to say that the following procedure worked for my case, but I cannot be sure that this can work for you and/or if this procedure can be dangerous for your system configuration.**

For me, worked this procedure.

- Install command_line_tools_os_x_mavericks_for_xcode_late_october_2013
  ( not sure if it is necessary, but i think so )
- Install Qt4.8.5 and set it up on QtCreator
- install [homebrew](http://brew.sh/)
- install apple-gcc42 and gdb using brew:

  brew tap homebrew/dupes

  brew install apple-gcc42

  brew install gdb

set up the compiler and GDB on QtCreator and then create your kit.

- codesign gdb following [this](http://panks.me/blog/2013/11/install-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks-from-source/) guide (scroll until you find
  "Generate Certificate for signing".

have fun.

in my case it was necessary to modify the makefile in order to set for
CFLAGS, CXXFLAGS and LFLAGS the value -mmacosx-version-min=10.6.

Answer (score 0):

All of the C++ code (Qt, your application, any C++ libraries that you use) must be compiled with the same C++ compiler.

Comment: they are included using "INCLUDEPATH += ...".
how can I check if they are being compiled with the same compiler used for the project?

Comment: @Fr.Usai What compiler did you use to compile Qt with? If you didn't build Qt yourself, you're likely to run into problems.